# How can i display two scaffold messenger in same scaffold (ScaffoldMessenger)

Tags: flutter, dart

I am displaying two different Scaffold messages(same context for both) on two different API (POST) calls. I  am using

```
final snackBar = SnackBar(
  content: Text('Yay! A SnackBar!'),
  action: SnackBarAction(
    label: 'Undo',
    onPressed: () {
      // Some code to undo the change.
    },
  ),
);


ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);
```

It is working first time for 1st api call. But when I call another API, the same first Scaffold is displayed with same message of the first API call. How can I display both with respective messages.

Comment: Please add your current code on where you are showing the `SnackBar` in both cases (here is [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)).

Comment: Currently all of your `SnackBars` displays your text `Yay! A SnackBar`. You have to make the content as a parameter to change your text accordingly.